# fmin_l_bfgs_b returns NaN as function value, but I don't get that

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

*Disclaimer: I know that I can't expect to fully resolve the issue without showing a neat and simple reproducible sample, but I hope that I get some pointers even without that*.

My code is of the form

```
from scipy import optimize
x, foo, result = optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b(myFunc, x0, approx_grad=True,
                                      bounds=someBounds)
```

where from [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html) I get that the second output is

> f : *float* - Value of func at the minimum.

Here, I get

```
>> print foo
nan
```

But if I try to recover that function value using the minimum that `fmin_l_bfgs_b` gave me, I get

```
>> myFunc(x)
20520.965701409703
```

here's the `result`:

```
{'warnflag': 2, 'task': 'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH', 'grad': array([  1.27146321e+12,   5.25635627e+11,   8.94617519e+11,
         2.90637658e+12,   1.16159650e+12]), 'nit': 5, 'funcalls': 490}
```

How is it possible that I get a numerical minimum while the minimizer claims it is `NaN`?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. The result you get is, that the gradient at `x` is not even near to zero, so the current x cannot be a local minimum. Also it tells you that there was a problem during the line search. If I had to guess I would say, that your function produces nan. Maybe you divide by zero, or you divide inf/inf? If you do not show your question, this cannot be answered, I guess.

Comment: @cel If my function produced `nan`, how can it be that when I try it with the minimizing `x`, that is  `myFunc(x)`, i do **not** get `nan`?

Comment: You've seen the description of 'warnflag' and 'task' keys of the `result` dict, have you? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html I suspect "LNSRCH" stands for "line search".

Comment: @FooBar, I did not get that. You cannot know what function values `func(x)` are evaluated during the line search procedure. I do not understand what you want to test with your function evaluation `myFunc(x)`. It just shows that for some arbitrary point `x` `f(x)` is not `nan`. It makes little sense to show that: you have to be sure it for all feasible `x`, `func(x) != nan`...

Comment: @cel `x` is not arbitrary, `x` is the return value of the minimizer. It is the exact vector for which the minimizer claims the function output is `nan` - isn't it?

Comment: @FooBar, no that's simply not true - you may want to look up what line search is. I guess without showing your function and your bounds this question cannot be answered properly. I would recommend going through your function by hand and see if terms can go to 0 or to infinity and see if that can be a problem for your evaluation. Without that information this question probably cannot be answered and should be closed instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems before and I found that convergence could not be reached if `x0` was of type `float32`. After casting it to `np.float64`, it would work like a charm.
That might not be the solution to your problem, but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The returned `warnflag` value is not 0. The minimizer is telling you the optimization did not converge, [see documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b.html). You are supposed to check the return status before assuming the minimum was found.